# Lambda AbstractMethodError with generics in a library

Tags: android, lambda, javadoc

I have an android library **which uses Java 8**, and has a default interface to base its other interfaces on. Something like this:

```
interface GenericListener<T extends Event>
{
    void onEvent(T event);
}

interface MyEventListener extends GenericListener<MyEvent>
{

    class MyEvent extends Event
    {
        ...
    }

   /**
    * Some javadoc explanation for this method
    */
    void onEvent(MyEvent event);

}

// Elsewhere in the library, there's one method to post all events to their
// listeners

void postEvent(GenericListener listener, Event event)
{
    listener.onEvent(event);
}
```

So the above works exactly how it should, at least until the introduction of lambdas. If someone implements MyEventListener as a lambda in their application, when postEvent() gets called, it throws an AbstractMethodError. If I remove the onEvent() method from MyEventListener, then it works fine. Ideally, I'd like to leave the onEvent() method implemented in the extending interface so that I can inject javadoc for that method differently for each interface which extends GenericListener.

I should note that if the MyEventListener interface is put into the same module as the app, then everything works as well.

Comment: Unable to reproduce with the given code. Please provide a full, (not) working example

Comment: Did you try on android?

Comment: Yes, using the android studio emulator

Comment: Interesting, just ran a quick test, and it worked. I wonder if it has something to do with the library being compiled already.

Comment: Ok, after fiddling around, it seems the interfaces have to be in a different module than the one using the lambda. If you move the Listener, and MyListener classes to a library module, you should be able to replicate the issue.

Comment: I've tried with this code in a libray module https://pastebin.com/XsXHzBqZ and this code in an app https://pastebin.com/KWc3NbGY and it is still working. Post the exact steps to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Found another caveat, the library module has to be set to use Java 8. I've posted a bug for android studio here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68977385. That issue has a zip of a simple project that replicates the issue.

Comment: Yeah, definetly a bug. If you run this snippet, you'll see that the lambda has an abstract method where the anonymous class doesn't: https://pastebin.com/8DxiHjf4 I suspect this is an issue of desugaring lambdas with generic interfaces

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 3.2 fixes this problem.